# What goes wrong with this regex definition?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The regex definition goes as

```
$regex_rule = '/^[[:alnum:]!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^_`{|}~@]{3,255}$/';
```

Basically it works well, but like **comma** symbol can also go through the validation, using PHP's **preg_match()**.

Comment: Unescaped hyphens `-` become a range in charclasses.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aO4wT7/1 https://regex101.com/r/aO4wT7/2